# How to forward a draft email on to another person without losing the original in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

When drafting a detailed email, I find sometimes I need to forward a copy of the email on to someone else for review or comment before sending on to the original recipient.

Previously I have handled this by either creating a new email and copying the contents through the clipboard or by changing the TO address of the original email, then re-creating a new email once the reviewer or commentor has replied. However this is seems to me to be the long/hard way to do this given you also have to manually copy the subject line as well.

Is there a way to just - for example - right click on the email in the drafts folder to forward it to someone. Or even easier forward it/duplicate it from directly inside the editing window itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Outlook Options dialog box, please click Mail in the left bar, then check the Open replies and forwards in a new window box in the Replies and Forwards section. And finally click the OK button.
[image]

Now, the Forward function has been activated under the draft situation.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, the simple method is the one you can see in the Outlook UI.

Dragging the draft into another email is probably simplest. If there's a right-click option available to "forward as attachment that will do the same thing but in fewer clicks. I just am not in front of an Outlook client to check whether that's an option.

But, considering you can press CTRL+N nearly anywhere in Outlook to open a new message, and then it is just a simple drag and drop to get the draft email, there isn't much to do to make that process simpler.